# What is the maximum inclination a geosynchronous orbit can have?

Tags: orbit, geosynchronous, inclination

A [geosynchronous orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geosynchronous_orbit) is one where a satellite's orbital period (more or less) matches a planet's rotation period. However, this is distinct from a *[geostationary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geostationary_orbit)* orbit, where a satellite must remain over the same spot on the Earth. In an [inclined geosynchronous orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclined_orbit#Inclined_geosynchronous_orbit), a satellite would trace out an analemma over the course of a sidereal day. Such an orbit would also slowly decay, requiring adjustment over time.

Since you can have a geosynchronous orbit that is inclined, what is the maximum inclination you can have before it is no longer considered "geosynchronous"?

Asking because I found an [interesting paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.07723) which considers the possibility of detecting aliens through geosynchronous satellites in orbit around their planets.

Comment: 180°, same as any other orbit.

Comment: @notovny Orbital inclinations go from -90° to 90°, not to 180°.

Comment: @Phileros Orbital inclinations of >90° are how retrograde orbits are traditionally expressed. I've never seen a negative orbital inclination in a list of orbital parameters, myself.

Comment: It would be important for a geosynchronous orbit, since it would correspond to the latitude of the spot it is geosynchronous over.

Comment: @Phiteros as the inclination is the angle between the orbit angular momentum vector and the Z axis of the reference frame, the domain is in fact 0-180, not -90-90.

Comment: Then I stand corrected.

Comment: A common inclination is 98.7°, polar and slightly retrograde for [sun-synchronous orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun-synchronous_orbit).

Answer (score 2):

There is no maximum inclination for that. As you point out, and as "[Fundamentals of Astrodynamics](https://store.doverpublications.com/0486600610.html)" by Bale et al. confirms in section 3.2.1, an inclined geosynchronous orbit traces out an analemma over a sidereal day. An equatorial geosynchronous orbit then simply traces out an analemma of height and width zero, i.e. a point-shaped one. At e.g. inclination 90° the orbit is over the poles, and traces out its [analemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analemma) over the entire planet.

Comment: @uhoh Check! Edited my answer correspondingly.